# Catching / Redirecting 404's (ASP.NET)

Tags: asp.net, module, handler, http-status-code-404

Ive noticed that when I request a page in ASP.NET (webforms) that does not exist, the 'StaticFile' handler deals with the error notification.

Id like to be a bit more helpful in these situations.

What is the correct way for me to intercept this 404, and as a result, run some code to redirect the user?

Two ways Ive thought of doing which I currently don't really like are:

1 - Create a module that basically does a `if (!file.exists($url){redirect to $correctedurl})`

2 - Modify the error.aspx.cs(or the default error page) to do something similar (yuck!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two areas that you have to modify in order to capture 404s.  The first is in IIS itself, which will take care of any non-aspx files such as css, jpg, js, etc.  The second is in the web.config of the app itself which will handle missing aspx's.

The link below shows how to accomplish this.

see [here](http://www.xefteri.com/articles/show.cfm?id=11)

Comment: hope you don't mind the edit.  The link is a great walk through, the question just needed a bit more describing what it's about.

Answer (score 1):

The web config has a [customErrors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc.aspx) section that lets you specify where to direct specific error codes.

If you would like to intercept the request when it is first made you will need a Global.asax and respond to the BeginRequest event. At that point you can determine if a file exist on the server and Response.Redirect on the context. Just make sure you understand every request goes through that event including JS files, CSS and images.
[HttpApplication Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication_members%28v=VS.71%29.aspx)

Comment: Problem being, the client navigation path is $RequestedUrl->$Custom404Page->$CorrectedURL, I dont want to hit three seperate pages, two should be enough.

Comment: No dude, you would create a class that implements IHttpHandler, create an entry in web.config/handlers/ where you could map it to specific or all extensions. Both ways would involve me checking to see if the page physically existed which is not good enough.

Comment: I do not see why your first comment is an issue $RequestedUrl->$Custom404Page->$CorrectedURL . Technically the user never hits $RequestedUrl page and I doubt they would notice a second redirect from your server.

Comment: @maxp: I'm not exactly sure why you think 2 redirects are unprofessional.  This is how it works.  Richards answer is probably the best though as opposed to setting up IIS to handle every extension through the asp.net framework, which would have a negative performance impact on the whole site.

Comment: @chris of course its not how it works... you don't need to hit the generic error page when you can intercept the error when it happens and apply logic to it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `HttpModule` that responds to the `Error`-event of your application. In here you can get access the `Exception` and `StatusCode` of the Response and if the Code is 404 (NotFound) you can respons accordingly to it. Usually rewriting the request, setting StatusCode to Found and clearing the `Exception`. That way customErrors in web.config wont be hit and the process will be $RequestedUrl -> $CorrectedURL.

This is an example of creating a HttpModule that responds to error events in asp.net.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/GlobalErrorHandler.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Just rock the CustomErrors in the web.Config

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors defaultRedirect="Error.htm"
                  mode="RemoteOnly">
      <error statusCode="404"
             redirect="~/NotFound.aspx"/>
    </customErrors>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```